# XML repeating item to array of String with index

Tags: java, xml, tibco

I need to convert a repeting items of a XML string to a simple string with index value.

```
<root>
    <items>
        <ammount>200</ammount>
        <qty>20</qty>
    </items>
    <items>
        <ammount>100</ammount>
        <qty>10</qty>
    </items>
    <name>ravi</name>
</root>
```

Expected out put is

```
name=ravi;items[0].amount=200;items[0].qty=20;items[1].amount=100;items[1].qty=10
```

Here is the Java code that I have added so far after parsing the XML string.

```
    private static String convertDocumentToString(Document doc) {

    StringBuffer sbItems = new StringBuffer();
    String strItem = "";
    try {
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        System.out.println("Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
        NodeList itemList = doc.getElementsByTagName("items");
        for (int i = 0; i < itemList.getLength(); i++) {
            NodeList childList = itemList.item(i).getChildNodes();
            for (int j = 0; j < childList.getLength(); j++) {
                Node childNode = childList.item(j);
                sbItems.append((strItem.concat(itemList.item(i).getNodeName() + "[" + i + "]." + childNode.getNodeName() + "=" + childNode.getTextContent() + ";")));
            }

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return sbItems.toString();
}
```

TIA.

Comment: Did you try anything? Can you show us the code? What is the actual problem?

Comment: What have you tried? We are not gonna code for you. And I do not see why you need to convert XML into some kind of indexed list? Please upgrade your question.

Comment: There's tons of ways to do this in Java. Which technologies can you use, or do you want to use? How does Tibco factor into this? And as others have stated, what have you tried?

Comment: I am not sure how easily I can make this indexed "items[0].amount" can be formed in java. I have done many normal xml parsing though. 
I need to use the same string in TIBCO tool to call a http back end. I tried doing in TIBCO but see no luck. So thought of writing small piece of java code...

Comment: Arindam, Which product are you using? BW? what exactly the use case?

Comment: @Rao I am using BW 5.9. My use case is to transform a xml string to a flat value pair string. Then the same string should be send as a post data to back system. Right now I am trying to do the same using Java with XML parsing.
Can some one also guide me how to differentiate the element which has sibling and which does not have ? In my ex. name has no sibling but items does have. I want to differentiate the same.